# Select Query with Where condition depending on list values in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've an sql table. I've also a list in my Asp.Net code (C#).

```
public static List listColumns = new List();
```

And listColumns contains 1,2,3...10 randomly. For example it can contains 1, 5, 6, 9. I want to make a query with this conditions. So, If the list has these values, my query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id=1 or id=5 or id=6 or id=9
```

The listColumns may contains different values and has different counts. How can I do this query regularly?

Comment: is it that `((System.Web.UI.MobileControls.List)listColumns).ListItem.Value` can have a string value with comma separated int types? Please show how the listColumns object contains these random int's.

Comment: They are strings. I fill them by: list.Items.Add(s);

Comment: But the user can only select one item at a time or is it multi-select? can you show us some more code?

Comment: list.Items.Clear();
        string values = DropDownList4.SelectedValue;
        string[] words = values.Split(',');
        
        foreach (string s in words)
            if (s != "" && s != string.Empty && s != null)
                list.Items.Add(s);

Comment: List is filled what is selected from dropdownlist. User can select anything from dropdown. Dropdown has some values like this: "1,2,6,9", "1,5,6" or "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9". etc.

Comment: Ok, changed my answer, please confirm my assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution without a `for` loop, but unfortunately also without a parameterized SQL statement:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public class test {
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    //List<int> listColumns = new List<int>(){ 1, 5, 6, 9};
    System.Collections.Generic.List<int> listColumns = new System.Collections.Generic.List<int>(){ 1, 5, 6, 9};
    string s = String.Join(", ", listColumns.Select(x => x.ToString()));

    string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN ({0})", s);
    Console.WriteLine(sql);
  }
}
```

Please note that using `select *` is considered as a bad practice

**edit** Here is some new code because your list is of type `System.Web.UI.MobileControls.List`

```
string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN ({0})", 
                 listColumns.ListItem.Value);
```

**edit 2** I have taken the code from your comment:

```
list.Items.Clear(); 
string values = DropDownList4.SelectedValue; 
string[] words = values.Split(','); 

foreach (string s in words) 
    if (s != "" && s != string.Empty && s != null)     
        list.Items.Add(s);
```

I guess that you have this on the dropdown changed event or something? and your dropdown has a string like "1,5,6,9" in the value.
If all my assumptions are correct you can use:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int> selectedValues = new     System.Collections.Generic.List<int>();

foreach (string s in words)
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        selectedValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
string ids = String.Join(", ", selectedValues.Select(x => x.ToString()));
string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN ({0})", ids);
```

Comment: I take an error: Error 1 'System.Web.UI.MobileControls.List' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MobileControls.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ehh the List object I was using was not of type `MobileControls` but of System.Collections.Generic.List http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ps. msdn says: `The System.Web.Mobile.dll assembly has been deprecated and should no longer be used. For information about how to develop ASP.NET mobile applications, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=157231` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.list%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
 //assume a list of int value name listColumns
  var listColumns = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 9 };
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append("SELECT * FROM Table");

   for (int i = 0; i < listColumns.Count; i++)
   {
       if (i == 0)
          {
             sb.Append(" where ");
             sb.Append(" id=" + listColumns[i]);
          }
        else
             sb.Append(" or id=" + listColumns[i]);
    }
   Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

pass query variable to sqlcommand

Comment: please use `StringBuilder` for string concatenation in a loop and secondly, I would prefer the use of parameters when building a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
//assume input is List of integers 
List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1,5,6,9 };
//build your SQL statement as below
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Table  WHERE id IN ({0})";
// add parameters for each id value 
string[] paramNames = ids.Select(
    (s, i) => "@id" + i.ToString()
).ToArray();

string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);
//set the parameter values
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(cmdText, inClause))) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ids.Count; i++) {
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], ids[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-SQL:

```
var listColumns = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 9 };
db.Table.Where(x => listColumns.Distinct().Contains(x.id)).ToString();
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id],
FROM [Table] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[id] IN (1, 5, 6, 9)
```

**EDIT**

An approach that yields parameterized SQL (not that it's all that useful if the number of parameters keeps changing):

```
listColumns.Distinct().Aggregate(db.Table, (current, c) => current.Where(x => c == x.id)).ToString();
```